# How to get element value using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>    
<content>
      <FingerPrintUserDetails>
        <UserID>e57645</UserID>
        <UserName>Jill</UserName>
        <FPData>AQAAABQAAAD0AAAAAQASAAEAWgAAAAAA8AAAAHfrWpB6BHZBL10voxpdxu2Km5XVNh*oUNC80Rvpql3RhlqOiBPeet6iRPwb/BdN1fCF4Y/WHbQ40*mqoUKqilgN7bUqNuXP7M299HUWtoAGEO3nDKXXAnHd7dgytZbmHVv*mRBPJDSRw9VY/R1yOIu2cCDlLM*F8Q1lvTfMFDdfwNZynI0e2ZauCF58f0UX56XLFBallaAauxP5mvvhUmcmc6ITg7RhH9wc4181kgPjCuZg38pQepE5U07XIa3hQP8fwxPzdprifXECgB1Z3pTXWQP0q4ZD0Inlbq6Gszo1ucPrhQA0jYQRXtJUVuyBeg</FPData>
        <Address>Pune</Address>
        <ContactNo>848488484884</ContactNo>
      </FingerPrintUserDetails>


      <FingerPrintUserDetails>
        <UserID>444</UserID>
        <UserName>John</UserName>
        <FPData>AQAAABQAAADkAAAAAQASAAEAZAAAAAAA4AAAAPLnmQ8FymAAHWYutR5pdtYvfDVmjsqLeli8tOSTFAtw6AkfA0r8XwrMzp9jFZJI7DlBk4G94BMq55gPEG7uBLZUNYrvhv0jDlDFMOjWGJ9RoWekFveTC*oZ7Tq/xmxuvY6FzLHVo*xzdKQI73Y0f9/eeMC0OgqnbQ3I0IP6cTkkKnTUZJOXKr7IFPHkjJAvCDmU7ec4vG50JHdBJIObmbzVcO0huTUQyE7CR1qYkUjmNFKgVKWPLRupEk4l/Ek0BuAba*9JlhBVUHzZuKbDQLc9lTFwevAgDuuAwxfZaLS*</FPData>
        <Address>nagpur</Address>
        <ContactNo>464645763</ContactNo>
      </FingerPrintUserDetails>


      <FingerPrintUserDetails>
        <UserID>5555</UserID>
        <UserName>Jack</UserName>
        <FPData>AQAAABQAAAAEAQAAAQASAAEAZAAAAAAA9AAAAPz5mQO3uTeXLfU5Mb74XbCX5rERGZFPQMVG1vPpX87306O5oURlYiIe5dasJ2S8NlBZu2UU3zaUpNnB7viYDB6*wfFlgtopn/WdbXW0Yhik3hj8nDreEmaK12To8qfAJx2ooq43i0wBIL*0Jkba*QpHIprSajrhnCg1PjOLMP37sEauJUwXJaoDR/PPQYIxTFE5kf8xzGlJmqiGejD*Y8R3ewU9yIrxkdQ0S//LCdacULt2QvS/I3APo/j0FAgSCOU3SBLdDL6UBPD4fLeEzo7uUIW8gUMThzZX*u2iUuNwJdqWC2NsFtWkUWt03sz3xYQpR8pLA4vrsUmldzUMWe8</FPData>
        <Address>beed</Address>
        <ContactNo>5745745747</ContactNo>
      </FingerPrintUserDetails>


    </content>
```

C#:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("E://BioEnable_Project//fp_project_using_xml//fp_project_using_xml//Capture_Data.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("FPData");
foreach(XmlElement node in nodes)
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.Value);
}
```

I have to check FPData value on each node..i use above code but not  getting..

Comment: What happens if you try? Is there an exception? If so, what is the message? What line is the exception thrown in? Please don't let us guess around on details that you could easily add to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XPath, provide the *full* path to the node.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/content/FingerPrintUserDetails/FPData");
```

What is happening is that there is no *direct* `FPData` node under the document root.

Comment: @lax - Forgot to start from the root. Added a `/` at the path start.

Comment: i have to get FPData where USerID="e57645"  how will be my code where UserID coming from textbox

Comment: @lax - That really is a _different_ question from the above. But this can be done with xpath as well: `"/content/FingerPrintUserDetails[UserID = 'e57645']/FPData"`. How you construct the XPath I leave to you...

Comment: @lax - Don't know what that means. I tested the above XPath with the XML file you posted and got a single `FPData` node.

Comment: i used in my code like this   XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/content/FingerPrintUserDetails['" + txtUserId.Text.Trim() + "']/FPData");

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("content/FingerPrintUserDetails");
```

it will return array of FingerPrintUserDetails, then find FPData in them

```
XmlNodeList res = nodes[index].SelectNodes("FPData");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ to XML:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XmlFilePath");
 var selectors = from elements in doc.Elements("content").Elements("FingerPrintUserDetails")
                 select elements;

foreach (var element in selectors)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(element.Element("FPData").Value);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("E://BioEnable_Project//fp_project_using_xml//fp_project_using_xml//Capture_Data.xml");
XmlNodeList lst =  doc.GetElementsByTagName("FingerPrintUserDetails");

foreach (XmlElement elem in lst)
{
    XmlNode pfData = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FPData")[0];
    MessageBox.Show(pfData.Value);
}
```